# MEP System traversal - cannot find BaseEquipment or Openconnector

Tags: revit-api, autodesk

### Intro

I'm working on a project where I need to traverse though all elements in a MEPSystem from the starting Mechanical Equipment. I found the 2 articles below by Jeremy Tammik which suggest a way to do this:

1. [Traversing and Exporting all MEP System Graphs](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/06/traversing-and-exporting-all-mep-system-graphs.html)
2. [MEP System Structure in Hierarchical JSON Graph](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/06/store-mep-systems-in-hierarchical-json-graph.html)

One of the reference I found in this articles in to the GitHub repository for [TraverseAllSystems](https://github.com/jeremytammik/TraverseAllSystems) and found that the release [2017.0.0.8](https://github.com/jeremytammik/TraverseAllSystems/tree/2017.0.0.8) works best for my need to be able to provide the data in a structured json format like below:

MEP System JSON format!

```json
{
  "id": 392200,
  "name": "Mitered Elbows / Taps",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 392203,
      "name": "Standard",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 392199,
          "name": "Mitered Elbows / Taps",
          "children": [
            {
              "id": 386552,
              "name": "450 x 200",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "id": 386555,
              "name": "450 x 200",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

### Problem

Now the problem is that this seems to be working fine in the [Sample Revit models](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit/getting-started/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2022/ENU/Revit-GetStarted/files/GUID-61EF2F22-3A1F-4317-B925-1E85F138BE88-htm.html) provided by Autodesk. But when I try this out in my project, I found that its working as expected.

After debugging for quite some time, I found that the [`m_system.BaseEquipment`](https://github.com/jeremytammik/TraverseAllSystems/blob/2017.0.0.8/TraverseAllSystems/TraversalTree.cs#L400) & [`openConnector`](https://github.com/jeremytammik/TraverseAllSystems/blob/2017.0.0.8/TraverseAllSystems/TraversalTree.cs#L444) in the [`TraversalTree.cs`](https://github.com/jeremytammik/TraverseAllSystems/blob/2017.0.0.8/TraverseAllSystems/TraversalTree.cs) class both return null and that's where the code is breaking because its not able to find the starting element which is the Mechanical Equipment. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to solve this?

Below is the starting part of the respective code that is causing this issue:

Code that breaks

m_system.BaseEquipment

```cs
private TreeNode GetStartingElementNode()
{
    TreeNode startingElementNode = null;

    FamilyInstance equipment = m_system.BaseEquipment; // returns null

// ...
```

openConnector

```cs
private Element GetOwnerOfOpenConnector()
{
    Element element = null;

    //
    // Get an element from the system's terminals
    ElementSet elements = m_system.Elements;
    foreach (Element ele in elements)
    {
        element = ele;
        break;
    }

    // Get the open connector recursively
    Connector openConnector = GetOpenConnector(element, null); // returns null

    return null != openConnector
        ? openConnector.Owner
        : null;
}
```

#### Other useful resources:

- [How to Iterate over elements by MEP System Name](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/how-to-iterate-over-elements-by-mep-system-name/td-p/7386520)
- [Revit MEP Programming: All Systems Go](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/files/cp4108_rme_api-1.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I was originally trying to figure why Jeremy's code is not working because I strongly believe Jeremy has addressed every possible scenario in his algorithm.

But after spending some time on debugging, I wanted to try if I can make some change to get it to work. I made the below change and was able to get the code to work as expected.

I'm not sure if this can lead to any possible inconsistensies in the future, but this solved my problem:

```cs
private TreeNode GetStartingElementNode()
{
    TreeNode startingElementNode = null;

    FamilyInstance equipment = m_system.BaseEquipment;

    // added the below if condition to look for Mechanical Equipment in the system elements
    if (equipment == null)
    {
        foreach (FamilyInstance element in m_system.Elements)
        {
            if (element.MEPModel is MechanicalEquipment)
            {

                equipment = element;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
// ...
```

Comment: Looks good to me. Thank you for sharing. Can you please clone the GitHub repo, and your changes to your local version, and create a pull request for me to integrate? What version of Revit are you working with, by the way? I would like to migrate the base repo from Revit 2017 to the version you are using first. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Jeremy. I created the PR [here](https://github.com/jeremytammik/TraverseAllSystems/pull/2). BTW, I'm using Revit 2021

Answer (score 0):

Hey Gangula (and Jeremy) I saw this post and was curious about the proposed solution of setting the starting element node by breaking on the first MechanicalEquipment element found. I feel for root equipment purposes one would prefer source equipment like a air handling unit or chiller compared to say inline or terminal equipment like a fan coil unit or UV water filter. Perhaps some additional logic to figure out from the equipment connectors what **FlowDir** and **MEPSystemClassification** correspond with a base equipment e.g. an AHU SupplyAir connector could only be FlowDir = Out and  ReturnAir connector be FlowDir = In. A downstream fan coil would have those in reverse.

If any MechanicalEquipment would suffice then maybe any element at all also would since you lose the "base" equipment factor anyway?

Comment: You're' almost right when you say that we can use any element, but any element would not work because the code only considers elements that are connected to the `End` ConnectorType since we would like to ignore previously evaluated elements. Hence choosing any Mechanical Equipment would work because that would only have one connected element from the current system. I could be wrong, feel free to comment.

Comment: Also an Air Handling Unit would ideally be the correct base equipment, but like I mentioned in above comment, using any mech equipment would suffice too.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).